# why this php global doesn't echo in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I'm new to PHP and I'm not sure why this doesn't work. I have done everything this page said http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php (example #1 Using global)... Why is it not working? it's frustrating.

This is a first attempt on wordpress plugins. First file contains:

```
function pp_sa_menu(){
        add_menu_page('Shadow Accounts Search', 'Shadow Accounts', 'manage_options', 'shadow_accounts', 'pp_sa_search');
}
add_action('admin_menu','pp_sa_menu');

function pp_sa_search(){
        include('shadow-accounts/admin/sa-admin.php');
}
```

then the `sa-admin.php` file is where the problem happens

```
<?php
$sandbox = true;

$phost = 'localhost';
$pus = 'user';
$ppas = 'pass';

$pus = 'Hello World';

function testFunc(){
    global $phost;
    return $phost;
}

echo testFunc(); //empty

function getForumAccounts(){
    global $pus;
    echo $pus; // empty
    echo 'test'; // shows 'test'
    echo $ppas; // empty

}
getForumAccounts();

?>
```

Comment: Works for me http://codepad.org/723HdnC5

Comment: hmmm no idea why it doesn't show me anything. Does that matter that it's inside wordpress as a plugin?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried with few different variables.. and nothing shows.. although when I just type `echo "text"` it shows that

Comment: Do you have output buffering enabled?

Comment: I just tried the 2nd method, didn't show anything either... this is a simple plugin in Wordpress which should just echo a variable. When I type echo 'test'; I can see that.. however if I use global variable, it's empty..

Comment: You have included sa-admin.php inside a function. That means that the variables it sets -- `$phost`, `$pus`, `$ppas` -- are *not* globals. They are local variables inside the `pp_sa_search` function. If you really want them to be global you must either declare them outside `pp_sa_search` (by including sa-admin.php outside of `pp_sa_search`), or by adding `global $phost, $pus, $ppas;` at the top of that file.

Comment: @Boann that makes sense... I would like to avoid making them globals if possible, but how else can I pass them into that function?

Comment: `getForumAccounts('localhost', 'user', 'pass');` ? Iunno. I don't know why you even need these variables. I'm sure WordPress must already provide database functions.

Comment: it works. Cheers... because it's going to connect to another database and compare some things

Comment: @TomaszGolinski Glad to hear a solution was found.

Comment: thanks Fred, the problem was like Boann said, those variables were not globals because of that one function which included the 2nd file.

Comment: You're welcome Tomasz.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work any different but:

```
$phost = 'localhost';

function getForumAccounts(){
  global $phost;
  return $phost;
}

echo getForumAccounts();
```

Function should be returning something. In this case its the variable and then you can echo that out or use the function in another way.

Answer (score 0):

it is working for me but I think you have not placed the php beginning tag `<?php`

```
<?php 
$phost = 'localhost';

function getForumAccounts(){
    global $phost;
    echo $phost;
}

getForumAccounts();
```